How to install Ubuntu Desktop in Legacy mode on a GPT USB drive?
I'd like to perform a full install of Ubuntu Desktop, in legacy mode, on a GPT usb disk. The disk in question is a 256GB Sandisk USB flash drive, and I'm using a 120GB partition as my root (/) partition. The disk is a high-performance drive, with write speeds north of 150 MB/s when formatted to ext4 (which I will be using for my root partition).
I've tried doing this, several times, using an installation disk running in legacy mode formatted using MBR; however if the target disk (that I specified above) is formatted using GPT, the installer automatically installs Ubuntu in UEFI mode with no option to specify otherwise. It only installs in legacy mode if the target disk uses MBR.
This poses a challenge, as I'd like to enjoy the benefits of GPT (particularly its support for up to 128 partitions), but while having Ubuntu in Legacy mode.
Often, in response to questions like this, commenters have asked the motivation for opting to use legacy rather than UEFI mode. My reasons for choosing legacy are: compatibility, I'm installing to a USB stick that will be used accross multiple PCs, and I'd like it to be compatible with older machines that only support legacy booting; and simplicity/speed, as having installed Ubuntu in both legacy and UEFI mode on USB drives several times, I've (somewhat surprisingly) observed significantly faster boot times using legacy mode (in my understanding this is due to a simpler boot process involving fewer hardware checks, etc.) than UEFI mode (which can be intolerably slow to boot, even on faster USB drives). I've also had more issues with UEFI installs on USB drives - for example, every time I perform a USB install of Ubuntu using UEFI, I have to manually move EFI files around to the right places before being able to boot normally (otherwise I have to manually select which EFI file to boot from using the file browser in my PC's boot device chooser) - I never have had to do this using legacy mode.
I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me how I can install Ubuntu, in legacy mode, on a GPT USB disk.

Please note, I'm quite new to asking questions on this community. If I've done something wrong, instead of downvoting right away, please consider leaving a comment and giving me a chance to edit my question first. Thanks =)

I have not done this recently, but booting the installation (live) USB in legacy mode had worked for me in the past. When you press a special key to boot from the live USB, you may see 2 USB option to boot from. Select the one without UEFI in the name.

See this answer for a bit more detail.

You mention Ubuntu, but give no specifics as to what product & thus what installer you're asking about (24.04 is available with three installers for Ubuntu & flavors). I've had no issues installing Ubuntu (using calamares ubiquity or ubuntu-desktop-installer) without any ESP; though I'm probably not using GPT.  I don't see any issue with installing using uEFI anyway; as uEFI uses the GPT to boot and legacy uses MBR, so its pretty easy to add the extra boot loader if it was added on install (yes I'd expect an install to add either one as determined at boot, but not both)

@guiverc I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 on the drive. I didn't mention which particular version as I presumed it would be the same process for most Ubuntu versions (I hoped that, if I left out the version, the answers would be useful to others with the same intention but using different versions). I've tried it with 23.10, 24.04, and the not-yet-released 24.10, all with the same issue. Would you like me to include the version in the question?

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server uses the subiquity installer, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop uses the ubuntu-desktop-installer as do many flavors, but some use calamares so its best if you're specific. Version should be included; plus product (Server? Desktop? flavor etc) as they influence the installer & options available at install often more than release (23.10 Desktop was available as 2 ISOs that used different installers - which 23.10 did you try as it had 4 total installers available...; we don't support 23.10 but without specifics as to 23.10 that detail tells us nothing!)

How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. Partitioning does not matter. You will need a tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partition on a gpt drive with bios_grub flag (if gparted). When first converting from BIOS to UEFI on gpt I used to add both ESP & bios_grub as only difference in boot modes is version of grub. Often lighter weight flavor works better for external drives. I use Kubuntu which is more mid-weight but even worked on my 2006 laptop in BIOS mode booting UEFI install on external SSD with a BIOS boot stanza on HDD of laptop to boot SSD. Both drives were gpt.

FYI:  You are aware that you can influence installers assumptions via the ISO write (refer @oldfred's suggestion; ie. I could cause installer to think uEFI on 2005 box that predates uEFI); so you must use appropriate settings or just clone ISO to install media (this will ensure ISO is unaltered & thus gets its defaults from your BIOS settings instead of unusual details on thumb-drive). The calamares installer won't create ESP by default if it detects legacy; ubuntu-desktop-installer does but doesn't require one to be created if using manual partitioning..
